# How to open link in new page in button control in item template in grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview

I have one item template in grid view, which contains one link. I want while clicking that button it should open in a new tab like `target= "_blank"`.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reportd Link"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" >
 <ItemTemplate>
 <button onclick="location.href='<%#Eval("ReportLinks")%>'" title='<%#Eval("ReportLinks")%>'> Link</button>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Why don't you actually use link `<a>` instead of button?

Comment: i want it should look in small size.if that link will be big , it will not dispaly good . column width issue will come @ander

Comment: @krishnamohan - Why not `LinkButton`? You can style it any manner.

Comment: yes u r right. but its already developed like that . any way i will make it link button and see wat problem comes

Comment: @krishnamohan try `target="_blank"` into the button tag...

Comment: target property not available in button@SankarRaj

Comment: Try this `onclick="window.open('<%#Eval("ReportLinks")%>'); return false;"` or  `onclick="<%# "window.open('" + Eval("ReportLinks") + "'); return false;"%>"` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to leave the button there you can change `location.href = url` call with `window.open(url, '_blank');` call, that would open a link in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/hg5u7815/) will work,

```
<input type="button" value="button name" onclick="window.open('http://www.website.com/page')" />
```

Comment: you can also use, onclick="window.open(this.href,'popUpWindow','height=400,width=600,left=10,top=10,,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no'); return false;"

Answer (score 0):

In gridview try this Code

```
<ItemTemplate> 
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Enter Details" OnClientClick="OpenWindow('<%#  Eval("id")%>',<%# Eval("start")) %>)" />
```

write a javascript methods

```
function OpenWindow(id,start)
{
 window.open('Default.aspx','_blank');
 window.location.assign(Default.aspx?goalText="+ id +"&ProductID="+ start)
}
```